# how to retrieve 1st 1000 records and then next 1000 and go on?

Tags: sql, netezza

```
select top 1000 from table1.
```

Then how do i continue with next 1000 and go on from the table. there are record count crosses millions, i have to take and process the info in a lengthy process..so, thought of using `Cursor` by retrieving 1000 and next 1000. any other best way?

Comment: There's no platform neutral way to do this. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: am using Nettezza, if SQL server then ..!?

Comment: I would avoid cursors unless it was determined that they are absolutely required, which they *may* be in some occasions. They are just often a PITA to deal with :(

Comment: Cursor is a bad idea..!?(Good to know atleast before i start..) then what would be better to iterate..?

Comment: @user1066231 It's not *always* a bad idea ... but almost always it is not needed. Dealing with SQL in sets was, well, how it really functions best overall. It just becomes awkward to "get out of" the procedural iteration of the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or higher then you can use the row_number() function:

[Using ROW_NUMBER() to paginate your data with SQL Server 2005 and ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12338/Using-ROW_NUMBER-to-paginate-your-data-with-SQL-Se)

But as Billy has commented, this isn't a generic SQL function.

A cursor is a very bad way of doing this, especially if you're doing disconnected querys, such as if a user is paging through results.

If you're using an older SQL Server then 2005, or you're looking for a generic method, then a common approach is by selecting the results into a temporary table that has an identity index, and then selecting from that table where index >= pagenumber * pageSize && index < (pagenumber * pageSize) + pageSize

Comment: If you're using Netezza, all I know is that it supports an older standard of SQL syntax, so it possibly won't have access to functions like row_number(), but you will have the ability to make temporary tables.  That said, If you're using a Netezza platform, it would suggest that you have a *lot* of data in there, and creating a temporary table just for pagination may be quite detrimental.

Comment: Netezza has the row_number() analytic function.